# How to bin values in a list into categories

Tags: python, matrix

For example, the double values in the first array `[1.2,4.6,3.7,11.2,13,5,18.9,0.3,20.0,26.7,1]`
now I want to create another array based on the first one with states 1, 2 and 3 
for every value in the first array that is in the range `[0,10)` add the value 1 in the second array
so the range `[0,10)` represents state 1 
the range `[10,20)` represents state 2 
the range `[20,30)` represents state 3

so at the end, the second array would look like `[1,1,1,2,2,2,1,3,3,1]`
This is a transition state array that will help to build the transition matrix in python **

Comment: Note that the actual output would be [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, *1*, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1] as the answers below show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If numpy is an option this is quite simple with [`np.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1.2,4.6,3.7,11.2,13,5,18.9,0.3,20.0,26.7,1])

np.digitize(a, (0,10,20))
# array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I'll leave it with the numpy approach for now, see if it is an option. Otherwise I'm thinking lists can be quite overkill for this numerical task @Ch3steR

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use numpy ([see yatu's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60758939/13081084)) or want to explicitly see a basic pure Python implementation, check out the below:

```
arr = [1.2,4.6,3.7,11.2,13,5,18.9,0.3,20.0,26.7,1]

def get_state(el):
 if 0 <= el < 10:
     return 1
 elif 10 <= el < 20:
     return 2
 elif 20 <= el < 30:
     return 3
 else:
     raise Exception(f"Unexpected value: {el}")

res = [get_state(el) for el in arr]
# [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1]
```